# System.OutofMemoryException using C#

Tags: c#, exception

Please find below my code to generate list of URLs.

```
List<string> urls = new  List<string>();   
int curr_Page = 1;
int end_Page = 2000;

for(int pages = curr_Page; pages < end_Page;pages++)
{
    for (int cno = 1;cno < 126001; cno++)   
    {   
          urls.Add("http://sources.domerig.com/list.php?cno=" + cno.ToString() + "&page=" + pages.ToString());   
    }
}
return  ScriptUtils.ArrayToDataTable("url", urls.ToArray());   
}
```

The above code is giving SystemOutOfMemoryException.

Is there any solution to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: what does  ScriptUtils.ArrayToDataTable do?

Comment: This will create a list of 251.875.999 strings * size of the string in mem. Why do you want a list of 252 million urls?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Actually, it will create a list of 251.874.000 strings :)

Comment: You can add more memory to your computer.

Comment: You should yield return the strings from a method.

Comment: @peer - that won't help. gcAllowVeryLargeObjects in .net 4 would enable ability to use larger than 2gb arrays on 64bit system, but in general I would review purpose and implementation of this code.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek, true, i was just cross editing it :)

Comment: What is the use of created DataTable? may be there is better alternative approach

Comment: this is auto generated code in a program called Visual Web Ripper. The actual code begins with  public class Script   
{      
 public static DataTable GetInputData(WrInputDataScriptArguments args)   
 {   
  try   
  {

Comment: @adt: What do you think a method `ArrayToDataTable` that takes an array does? I assume it takes an array, creates a `DataTable` and returns that ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I suspect some sneaky thing is also happening there :)

Comment: @adt: the only _sneaky_ is that it takes a column name and a `string[]` and puts all in a new `DataTable` with one column and throws the array into the garbage can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will create a list of 251,874,000 strings. Then you create a new array from it with `ToArray`. After that you call `ArrayToDataTable` which sems to create a new `DataTable` from it.

And you are wondering why you get an `OutOfMemoryException`? Why?

If you need to create a `DataTable` with one column `Url`, you can do that in the first place:

```
DataTable tblUrls = new DataTable();
tblUrls.Columns.Add("Url");
for(int pages = curr_Page; pages < end_Page;pages++)
{
    for (int cno = 1;cno < 126001; cno++)   
    {   
        tblUrls.Rows.Add("http://sources.domerig.com/list.php?cno=" + cno.ToString() + "&page=" + pages.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for you response but I am wondering if there is any way to change to code to find solution to this.

Comment: @user2806353: What's wrong with my suggestion to create the `DataTable` in the first place without the lists and the arrays?

Comment: This is actually a auto generated Code. The actual code begins withpublic class Script   
{      
 public static DataTable GetInputData(WrInputDataScriptArguments args)   
 {   
  try   
  {

Comment: Additional to the better code (less arrays/Lists) you can still try out the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects attribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx

Comment: @user2806353: _What_ is autogenerated and _what_ autogenerates this code? I've shown you how to create the table yourself. Now you just have to return it from `GetInputData`.

Comment: Thank you Tim... Thanks to all.